# how to filter all items that includes all elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

*I am Wondering how i can look up for all the elements of the Array. If all are included then i want to show them.
As an example :

```js
const data = [

  {
  "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["React", "Sass"]
  },
  
  {
  "languages": ["Python"],
    "tools": ["Vue", "Sass"]
  },
  
  {
  "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["Vue"]
  }

]


const newArr = ["Html","CSS"]
const newJobs = data.filter((item) => item.languages.includes(...newArr) || item.tools.includes(...newArr))
```

I get with this solution the result for each element but i want to check all of them.*

(The code is just an example the file has more data and Html and CSS is included too)

Comment: What do you mean by "check all of them?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `some()` method to filter if one element in the `searchStrings` array matches.

```js
const data = [{
    "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["React", "Sass"]
  },

  {
    "languages": ["Python"],
    "tools": ["Vue", "Sass"]
  },

  {
    "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["Vue"]
  }
];


const searchStrings = ["Python", "React"];

const result = data.filter((item) => {
  return searchStrings.some((str) => {
    return item.languages.includes(str) || item.tools.includes(str);
  });
});

console.log(result); // should show first 2 items from array
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  instead of some(), every() helped me out